# Parsing and displaying large file

Tags: parsing, scalability

I'm working on a tool that takes a text file, consisted of many lines of data, parsing it and displaying the data in a Windows Forms table (ListView). One of the features of the tool is the ability to filter specific columns according to user input. When working with reasonably-sized files, there's no problem. However, I'm required to handle files that are 500MB and even 1GB (with millions of text lines parsed). My general question is - what is  the best way to do this?

Some more specific questions:
1. Initially, should I read the whole file and parse it, or should I read it in chunks and read more only when required (when the user scrolls down)?
2. If I do not read the whole file, how do I implement the filter feature? When I filter I practically search for a certain term, so I can't not read the whole file.
3. How should the filter be implemented? Is there a smart way to do this but clearing the display and going over each line to check for the filter condition?
4. How should I handle the parsed data? Keep it in a separate data structure? Or only hold it in the display?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1) I would read only the data required to display the initial page and then spawn a background thread to load the remaining data so it is in memory when the user wants to scroll/filter.

3) For the filtering I'd probably use an in memory database, it'll be able to deal with doing the filtering much quicker than anything you write (no offence!).

4) As above, store it in an in memory database.  SqlLite allows you to create in memory database and i'm sure there are plenty of alternatives.